How to understand calculation of step size in voxel terrain renderer?
I was following the Pikuma's Voxel space terrain rendering video.
I understood almost everything that he described in the video except the following point, where he described the the equation to calculate step size for deltaX and deltaY:

for (int i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
  for (int z = 1; z < camera.zfar; z++) {

$$\Delta x = \frac{pl.x+\left[\frac{(pr.x-pl.x)}{320}*i\right]}{camera.zfar}$$
  }
}

He did not explained much about this equation in the video, so my questions is how did he deduce this equation? Or put another way, what is the intuition behind this?

These things are rather arbitrary and can depend on many factors. Unlike modern triangle-based rendering, with raycasting, there isn't really any single canon approach when it comes to projection math. It's more important to figure out how to build them, than to understand any one implementation. I guarantee you that with some experimentation, you could figure out your own formula that works just as well.

So, now that I've looked at it properly, yeah it's fairly straightforward.
He's taking the difference across that whole forward edge, in world space, and splitting that difference into steps of 1/320th each -- linearly interpolating from one edge of the arc to the other edge, in small increments, that are for each screen column -- of which I assume, by the divider, there are 320 in this example. This is done because it's much cheaper to calculate this way, than by using trig to determine every single ray's end point on the near or far planes (zNear, zFar).
pl.x + (pr.x - pl.x) / 320, where p.x at any point runs between 0..320 is as the linear interpolation formula lerpedValue = min + (max - min) * t, where t is an inverse fractional value (0.0 .. 1.0) that replaces the / 320. * i moves us along that vector in small steps.
As for the division by camera.zfar, this means that the final result is a projected screen space position, i.e. it accounts for perspective, meaning that objects appear smaller in the distance, and larger close up. At a distance of exactly 1, this term will do nothing (divide by 1), which is often considered the near plane zNear and de facto focal point of a raycaster.
Usually, division by z is NOT done using zFar which is typically a constant value, but rather using the actual calculated z (zCamera - zObject or - zVertex) at each step along the ray.

Yeah, that makes a lot of sense now, many thanks for the explanation. Highly appreciated.
